# Find MAX(SalesDate) of a customer by Sales Rep

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to find Min sales date and Max sales date by Sales Rep for customers. For a customer, the sales rep  gets change over the period of time. So Max sale date will be Min sales date of next sales rep of the customer.

```
CREATE TABLE REPSALES (Customer_Number NVARCHAR(10),Document_Rep   NVARCHAR(10) ,document_date  DATE)

INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','DD','2016-01-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','DD','2016-05-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','DD','2016-11-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','LL','2017-12-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','LL','2018-05-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','LL','2021-12-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','BB','2022-01-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 5','BB','2022-04-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 4','AA','2017-02-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 4','AA','2021-08-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 4','CC','2021-01-01')
INSERT INTO REPSALES VALUES ( ' 4','CC','2021-06-01')
```

Expected output:

| Customer_Number | Document_Rep | MinSalesDate | MaxSaledate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | AA | 01/02/2017 | 31/12/2020 |
| 4 | CC | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2022 |
| 5 | DD | 01/01/2016 | 30/11/2017 |
| 5 | LL | 01/12/2017 | 31/12/2021 |
| 5 | BB | 01/01/2022 | 31/12/2022 |

MinSalesDate is correct but Maxsalesdate is not coming correct. Can you please how to achieve this result.
I have written this SQL query

```
select 
    s.Customer_Number,Document_Rep, 
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, min(document_date)), 0) MinSalesDate,
    min(MaxSaleDate.Maxsalesdate)-1 MaxSaledate
from
REPSALES s
inner join  (
        select Customer_Number,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, min(document_date)), 0) Maxsalesdate,
        row_number() over(partition by Customer_Number 
        order by DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, min(document_date)), 0) ) seq
        from REPSALES 
        group by Customer_Number,Document_Rep)MaxSaleDate 
on MaxSaleDate.Customer_Number =s.Customer_Number
where  seq >1
group by s.Customer_Number,Document_Rep
ORDER BY s.Customer_Number,min(document_date)
```

Comment: `Max sale date will be Min sales date of next sales rep of the customer` Just curious why is this so?

Comment: Also where did this date `31/12/2022` comes from ?

Comment: Document Rep is slow moving dimension. To find , till when the document rep was handling the customer,  is when the next rep started handling the customer -1 day. 
Current Document rep wont have max sale date, so for that we are putting end of the current year.
Thanks for the Answer. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lead()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the next minimum `document_date` by `Customer_Number`. [coalesce()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to return the date or `2022-12-31` (which you didn't explain how this date comes about) if it is null.

```
with cte as
(
    select Customer_Number, Document_Rep, 
           MinSalesDate = min(document_date), 
           MaxSalesDate = max(document_date),
           NextMinDate = lead(min(document_date)) over (partition by Customer_Number 
                                                         order by min(document_date))
    from   REPSALES
    group by Customer_Number, Document_Rep
) 
select Customer_Number, Document_Rep, MinSalesDate, 
       MaxSalesDate = coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, NextMinDate), '20221231')
from   cte
order by Customer_Number, Document_Rep
```